# How to enable/disable dropdown field after selecting an option list item in boostrap

Tags: javascript, php, css

`

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <select class="form-control m-bot15">
           <option>All Students</option>
                                            <option>Faculty</option>
                                            <option>Department</option>
                                            <option>Program</option>
          </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                                    
         <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <select class="form-control m-bot15">
                                            <option>Faculty of Science</option>
                                            <option>Faculty of Arts</option>
                                            <option>Faculty of Management</option>
          </select>
                                    </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <select class="form-control m-bot15">
                                            <option>Department of mathematics</option>
                                            <option>Department of Statistics</option>
                                            <option>Department of Biology</option>
          </select>
                                    </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <select class="form-control m-bot15">
                                            <option>Architecture Program</option>
                                            <option>Computer science Program</option>
                                            <option>Chemical Engineering Program</option>
          </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

`How can I enable/disable a form item(dropdown 1 menu) field  in bootstrap after selecting another form item(dropdown 1) with Javascript. 
Here is a picture of my form items [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bJYM.png)

Comment: Can you add some code that you tried?

Comment: not specific to bootstrap really, you can use javascript to listen for an appropriate event on one field, and take action to set the disabled property of the other field. You can easily google both of those. Did you try anything so far?

Comment: didn't try anything am just a beginner in web programming

Comment: Your basic HTML and css code atleast?